# Проблема с тегами в UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, visual-studio-2015

В дизайнере пытаюсь создать `NavigationView` или `PersonPicture` но они подчёркиваются и вот какие ошибки:

> PersonPicture is not supported in a Windows Universal project
>
> The type 'PersonPicture' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Стоит последний Creators Update.

Comment: А сам проект для какой версии Windows?

Comment: @Андрей Target version - 14393 Anniversary edition: Min version - 10586

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для использования `NavigationVie` или `PersonPicture` необходимо установить в настройках проекта Targeting, Min version в `Windows 10 Fall Cretors Update (10.0; Build 16299)`, в более ранних версиях они недоступны.

И да, вам нужно установить Visual Studio 2017, в младших версиях это SDK не поддерживается.

Comment: У меня максимально возможная версия - это 14393. Надо vs обновить или что-то ещё?

Comment: я так понял, что нужно vs17 ставить? Вот эта ссылка говорит об этом: https://developer.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

Comment: Судя по всему - да, нужно установить VS2017